# Solve an equation with mod operator

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, modular-arithmetic

Consider the following equation
$$mod(x+100/x,5)=1.$$
How can we solve it with $x>0$?

First of all, the function $x+100/x$ is a continuous function with range $[20, \infty)$, therefore, it must has solutions. Then, it can be checked that the solutions are discrete, but how can we express them?

Comment: Well, the solutions are those of $x + \frac{100}{x} = 5n + 1$ for integers $n\geq 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer we employ the most general view, interpreting $100/x\bmod 5$ as modular fraction whenever it exists, i.e. when $5$ doesn't divide its  denominator when reduced to least terms.

Let  $100/x = a/b\,$ in least terms. If $\,25\nmid x\,$ then then we can cancel at most one factor of $\,5\,$ so $\,5\mid a,\, 5\nmid b\,$ so $\,100/x = a/b := ab^{-1}\equiv 0,\,$ so $\,1\equiv x+100/x\equiv x,\,$ i.e.  $\,x=1,6,11,\ldots$.

Else $\,25\mid x\,$ so $\,x = 25k\,$ and $\,5\nmid k\,$ (else $5\nmid a,\ 5\mid b\,$ so $\,a/b\,$ does not exist $\!\bmod 5)$. Hence  $\,1\equiv x+100/x\equiv 25k+4/k\equiv 4/k\iff k\equiv 4,\,$ so $\,k = 4+5n\,$ thus $\,x = 25k = 25(4+5n) = 100+125n = 100,225,350,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Using that the RHS must be an integer, show that $x$ must be an integer such that $1 \le x \le 100$ and that it must divide $100,$ then use that $100 = 1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 5^2$ to find all the divisor of $100,$ then test which ones work.

**Spoiler alert**: Only $1$ and $100$ work.

Comment: If we allow modular fractions then there are more solutions - see my answer.